# How to send POST request by Spring cloud Feign

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

It's my Feign interface

```
@FeignClient(
        name="mpi",
        url="${mpi.url}",
        configuration = FeignSimpleEncoderConfig.class
)
public interface MpiClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getPAReq(@QueryMap Map<String, String> queryMap
    );
}
```

and my custom configuration

```
public class FeignSimpleEncoderConfig {
    public static final int FIVE_SECONDS = 5000;

    @Bean
    public Logger.Level feignLogger() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }

    @Bean
    public Request.Options options() {
        return new Request.Options(FIVE_SECONDS, FIVE_SECONDS);
    }

    @Bean 
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() {
        return Feign.builder()
                .encoder(new FormEncoder());
    }
}
```

If I send request like this I see that my request send Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8.
But if I set content type

```
consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

I've this error message

```
feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.HashMap] and content type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.support.SpringEncoder.encode(SpringEncoder.java:108) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
```

How to send POST request, I think I should make something more with Encoder.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you should change your Feign interface like this:

```
@FeignClient (
    configuration = FeignSimpleEncoderConfig.class
)
public interface MpiClient {
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
   ResponseEntity<String> getPAReq(Map<String, ?> queryMap);
}
```

Then you should set the encoder during feign configuration:

```
public class FeignSimpleEncoderConfig {
    @Bean
    public Encoder encoder() {
        return new FormEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the Encoder bean in my project (spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE and feign-form:3.4.1 & feign-form-spring:3.4.1 ) but I have a problem with FormEncoder class.  The problem is that I can't import feign.form.FormEncoder. Any suggestion?  Thanks

Comment: I don't know. I've used spring-boot 1.3.8

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that Map is not valid for form body. MultiValueMap works just fine.

Feign client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "name", url="url", configuration = FromUrlEncodedClientConfiguration.class)
public interface PayPalFeignClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    String foo(MultiValueMap<String, ?> formParams);
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
public class FromUrlEncodedClientConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    Encoder feignFormEncoder() {
        return new FormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(this.messageConverters));
    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
compile group: 'io.github.openfeign.form', name: 'feign-form', version: '2.0.2'
compile group: 'io.github.openfeign.form', name: 'feign-form-spring', version: '2.0.5'
```

After that all you have to do is call it with a MultivalueMap parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the correct encoder for handle form encoded request

you can specify multi encoder example json/xml/formhttpurl encoded

```
@Bean
public Encoder feignEncoder() {
    ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> objectFactory = () ->
            new HttpMessageConverters(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    return new SpringEncoder(objectFactory);
}
```

Important FormHttpMessageConverter serialize only MultiValueMap subsclass

Comment: And how do you receive the key-value map with Feign?

Answer (score 0):

im my case it was due to outdated version of lombok, updating to `1.18.16` resolve it